# Can android phones exchange application data directly through mobile networks?

Tags: android, networking, mobile

i'm thinking of building an application which will requires communication between 2 android devices. I'm trying to establish a direct connections between 2 devices through the data plan (internet?).

Is it possible or i have to go through server?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking) or if the devices are close together Bluetooth. What are you trying to do? It is highly probable someone has built something already that you can use, for example there are various companies offering multiplayer SDKs.